# 'docker build: how does version pinning invalidate the build cache?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In [dockerfile_best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#general-guidelines-and-recommendations), I read, in relation to using `apt install`:

> Version pinning forces the build to retrieve a particular version regardless of what’s in the cache. This technique can also reduce failures due to unanticipated changes in required packages.

I don't see how that works... wouldn't docker need to introspect the `apt` command to achieve that? As-in, verify that the `RUN` instruction contains an `apt install` directive, together with an expression that would constitute a pinned apt package?

Can anyone offer some insight?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All docker does is look at the string you run, along with the environment you pass in, and compare it to other images in the build cache. If you have a Dockerfile that doesn't pin a package, like:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    package-foo
```

and you first run this when version 1.2 is the current latest, and then run the same command again after 1.3 gets released, docker will see the command is identical, and reuse the build cache from the previous build of the image, rather than pulling the newer version of that package.

---

If instead you specify a version like:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    package-foo=1.2.*
```

And then rebuild with an updated Dockerfile containing a different version pinned:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    package-foo=1.3.*
```

The second build will be a different command to run, and therefore force docker to rerun the build without the cache from the previous run. This also has the advantage that a 1.4 release doesn't get pulled in unexpectedly (e.g. if an earlier line breaks the cache or the cache gets removed/disabled).

---

If you just want the most recent versions of these packages, regardless of the cache, then you can skip version pinning and either intentionally break the cache or disable the cache. To disable the cache, you can build with the flag `--no-cache`. To intentionally break the cache, you can pass a changing build arg with something like:

```
docker build --build-arg "TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s)" .
```

And a Dockerfile that defines that build arg before you want to break the cache:

```
ARG TIMESTAMP
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    package-foo
```

Comment: Thanks @BMitch. I suspected as-much. I think the referenced documentation throws a bum steer: I read it as stating that version pinning is responsible for skipping the cache.

Comment: Maybe a shorter answer: read "regardless of what’s in the cache" as "regardless of what’s in the `apt` cache". That, combined with the fact that different people building the image at different times might get different versions of the `apt` cache, explains it, I think.

Comment: @jazzdelightsme more generically, any time you run the same command, and that command has external dependencies that change over time, docker has no way to know the build cache is invalid and it needs to recreate the layer rather than reusing the build cache. So you need to somehow change that command (with a pinned version or changing arg) to force the build cache to invalidate.